# How can I trace the highest value in a matrix until I go to a cell in the matrix with zero value?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to start with the highest value in the matrix (i,j). Then, go backwards to one of positions (i-1,j), (i, j-1), and (i-1, j-1) depending on the direction of movement used to construct the matrix. This method is used throughout until a matrix cell with zero value is reached.The above image shows what I want, I need to trace those marked in blue. I know there is a max function in matlab.

[image]

Comment: The aim of tracing the highest values back to zero in the matrix is because each index of that highest value represents the best local alignment between the two strings this is used in the Smith Waterman Algorithm. Hope this made it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you try to do...

Suppose `M` is your matrix:

```
result=[];
[~,ind]=max(M(:));
[r,c]=ind2sub(size(M),ind);
result=[result; r c];

while M(r,c)~=0

  [~,f]=max([M(r-1,c),M(r,c-1),M(r-1,c-1)]);
  switch f
    case 1
      r=r-1;
    case 2
      c=c-1;
    case 3
      r=r-1;
      c=c-1;
  end

  result=[result; r c];
end
```

Then, `result` is a `2 x n` matrix, where each row is the indexes of one step- from the upper to lower.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It was really helpful and I what I needed!